# Stability of a critical point

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a question about the stability of a critical point of the system:

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = \begin{bmatrix} 4 & -26 \\ 1 & -6 \end{bmatrix}x + \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}.$$

I have determined that the critical point in question is $(6,1)$ but cannot determine its stability. The options are saddle point, stable spiral, or asymptotically stable node.
Also, if there is a good way to plot it so I can just see it that would be a huge help too! Thanks

Comment: Have you computed the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of your matrix?

Comment: The eigenvalues suffice, and even, not their exact value is needed...

Comment: so i got the eigenvalues to be -1-i and -1+i and eigenvectors to be [26,5+i] and [26,5-i]. i'm not aware of a way to plot imaginary numbers to get a sense of its stability

Comment: Well I am not sure about terminology I learned it 20 years ago but since the real part of your eigen values is negative you have all solutions asymtoticially converge to your stationary point, namely it is stable. The phase porttari will be spiral since you have imaginary part of your eigen values.

Comment: @user2880566 You mean you do not know how to deduce the nature of the fixed point from the pair of eigenvalues?